# German Umlaute incorrectly displayed PyCharm SQL Answerset

Tags: sql, pycharm, teradata

I expect (somehow) that this is a very easy to solve issue...still, I spent a couple of hours googling and couldn't find a solution to my issue.

I use PyCharm 2021.2 Pro Edition to query an SQL database (Teradata 16.2). I struggle to get German Umlaute displayed correctly in answerset displayed within PyCharm.

[For example the city "Köln" is shown as this...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/923Xv.png)

I tried using different SQL charsets in PyCharm but without any success...Using Teradata SQL Assistant I do not have this issue.

Does anyone have an idea? Really appreciate your support!

Many thanks & cheers

desp_user

Comment: What’s the ascii value for that character, as stored in your database? Knowing this will allow you to confirm  that the character is stored correctly and this is definitely a display issue

Comment: you need to check which datatape  the city column as and then chekcm the connection string, if it has the same character set and collation, you should have utf8mb4 all the way

Comment: Seems your session character set is set to ASCII, check your connection properties